# Java 8 to Java 19 migration of RowSet

Tags: java, mysql, sql, rowset

When migrating my project to Java 19, I am getting this error related to our use of RowSet:

> cannot access class com.sun.rowset.CachedRowSetImpl (in module java.sql.rowset) because module java.sql.rowset does not export com.sun.rowset to module

and this is my code

```
import javax.sql.rowset.*;
import com.sun.rowset.CachedRowSetImpl;
import java.sql.*;
import javax.sql.rowset.CachedRowSet;
public static ResultSet dbExecuteQuery(String queryStmt) throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException {
    //Declare statement, resultSet and CachedResultSet as null
    Statement stmt = null;
    ResultSet resultSet = null;
    CachedRowSetImpl crs = null;
    try {
        //Connect to DB (Establish Oracle Connection)
        dbConnect();
        System.out.println("Select statement: " + queryStmt + "\n");

        //Create statement
        stmt = conn.createStatement();

        //Execute select (query) operation
        resultSet = stmt.executeQuery(queryStmt);

        //CachedRowSet Implementation
        //In order to prevent "java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: Closed Connection: next" error
        //We are using CachedRowSet
        crs = new CachedRowSetImpl();
        crs.populate(resultSet);
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.out.println("Problem occurred at executeQuery operation : " + e);
        throw e;
    } finally {
        if (resultSet != null) {
            //Close resultSet
            resultSet.close();
        }
        if (stmt != null) {
            //Close Statement
            stmt.close();
        }
        //Close connection
        dbDisconnect();
    }
    //Return CachedRowSet
    return crs;
}
```

I try because I don't know how to solve my problem and i expect that this problem will be solve

Answer (score 2):

`com.sun.rowset.CachedRowSetImpl` is a JDBC implementation detail. By historic convention all the classes under `com.sun` package are considered implementation detail. The distinction between JDK implementation detail and interface was enforced with the introduction of [Java 9 module system](https://www.oracle.com/corporate/features/understanding-java-9-modules.html).

In short you don't want to write your code depending on the JDK implementation details as they can change without warning.

See [How to Use CachedRowSet in JDBC](https://www.codejava.net/java-se/jdbc/how-to-use-cachedrowset-in-jdbc), section 3. Creating a CachedRowSet Object,  which shows how to create the same object using `RowSetProvider` and a `CachedRowSet` interface:

```
RowSetFactory rsf = RowSetProvider.newFactory();
CachedRowSet crs = rsf.createCachedRowSet();
```

Comment: I would like to ask you if you would be able to transform this code to be with RowSetProvider and CachedRowSet, because I don't know how to do it, I'm just learning JavaFX, please